# Usage of Google’s Material Design Paper examples?

Tags: google-material-design

I do not clearly understand what `Paper` (https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html) in Google Material Design is. What is the difference between `Paper` and `Card`? Actually, I understand what `Card` is, and where and how to use it. But `Paper` has almost the same characteristics. I can create `Paper`'s seams using `Card`s. What for is `Paper` introduced? Could you give same examples of `Paper` usage and when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Material Design *is a metaphor inspired by paper and ink* (real paper). Thats why they talk about paper as the fundamental, not a specific part as cards does.

> Google took paper to heart as a fundamental influence of the design. Google Design Lead for Andriod Matias Duarte explained to Fast Company that Material Design is looking to improve pixels form just having color and instead leverage your screen to change shape and depth of the pixels in response to a touch. In order to bring the most realistic experience into the digital world, they studied actual paper. The designers made paper icons with various layers to see how shadows were actually cast. Although real paper cannot morph and manipulate like the cardstock within Material Design’s UI, it helped to study it anyhow. After all, Material Design is making headway within the design community. More importantly, it will be a big part of design for Google as they roll it out. Even if Material Design wasn’t making headway, it’s still crucial to test your design, as it will impact users.

[image]

http://www.joomlavision.com/point-material-design/